# How to configure Mysql Server to maximize performance

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I hold a server with 12 cores CPU, 16GB RAM and 128GB SSD, using Centos as operating system, mainly for MySQL server. But I found that server always process queries with bad performance. I am not sure whether I configure my server correctly or not, who can give me a config file adapt to the current performance of my server(temporarily excludes problems caused by tables design).

More information about my use case and problems I met:

1. more than 80 schemas in my database, each schema includes 30 tables and used by different server applications.
2. querys becomes slow when some tables contains more than 10000 rows, and it will influence performance of all queries. What I found in process monitor is usage of CPU and RAM up to almost 100%.

Comment: Question seems not to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ?

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: High CPU means either poor indexing or poorly formulated queries.  Show us the slowest queries for help.  The [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) can help find the slowpokes.

Comment: @Luuk - It is on topic because the configuration is rarely the solution to a performance problem.

Comment: @RickJames: I was thinking so because 7. "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools"   And the statements: "More than 80 schemas" / "will influence performance of all queries".   Definitely more info is needed...

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, among all system variables, the innodb_buffer_pool_size is regarded as the most important variable for the entire MySQL server. Unfortunately, a lot of users don't have the faintest idea of its existence, making their MySQL DB reduced to running at the default 128MB buffer pool. I would absolutely recommend you setting a high value (consider half of your ram if the server is dedicated for MySQL) for the innodb_buffer_pool_size variable in the options file. Below is a typical template of options file suggested by the gurus from Percona in their book High Performance MySQL 3rd edition. Fine-tuning is by no means an easy task. By reading from the professionals' experience, you are making steady progress though.

```
[mysqld]
# GENERAL
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid_file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
user = mysql
port = 3306
storage_engine = InnoDB
# INNODB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = <value>
innodb_log_file_size = <value>
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
# MyISAM
key_buffer_size = <value>
# LOGGING
log_error = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_slow_queries = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
# OTHER
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
max_connections = <value>
thread_cache_size = <value>
table_cache_size = <value>
open_files_limit = 65535
[client]
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port = 3306
```

Comment: *Nothing* is 'regarded unanimously'. Don't make unsubstantiable assertions.

Comment: If it were I/O-bound, I would look at the buffer_pool_size.  (Too high == swapping; too low == inadequate caching.)  CPU points to indexing and/or query formulation.

Comment: @user207421
I have omitted the inappropriate adverb. Still , the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` system variable is substantial enough to prioritize due to its default value being too minor. This has been agreed by gurus from books and webs, and it came naturally to me when people start complaining about poor performance. Last time when I was doing some tests for a Corp. MySQL DB which suffered, it was the system variable to blame. I meant no offense, but if you have some in mind that is equally important from past experience , please contribute.

Comment: @blabla_bingo  Your template has SIX <value> global variable options that seem to be important.  You provide advice (half of your ram) for only the first element.  How is gensa leung supposed to get a clue on the OTHER five global variables that would be reasonable?